# Use environment variable for part of full path

Tags: linux, bash

How would I create an environment variable (maybe that's not the right word?) to use as a shortcut for very long paths? However, I don't want it to be the full path. I know how to set the absolute path in bashrc but what I want is something like:

```
cd $MYPATH/further/down/path/
```

How do I setup `$MYPATH` to use in this way? Whenever I try to google for this all that comes back are aliases for the full path which I do not want.

edit #1) I want the path to be persistent for each new terminal session. So I am looking for a command to put in bashrc. doing `alias MYPATH=~/my/path` does not work. I'm sure there is a simple command that I'm just not aware of that does what I want.

Comment: If you set `MYPATH` to the path you want, then what's the problem? `cd` will work because bash evaluates env. vars... unclear... please [edit] to explain better.

Comment: besides CDPATH you can also use alias for stuff you often visit `alias work=cd /...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works exactly as you think it would. If you define

```
export MYPATH=/home/user
```

then you can use it like

```
cd $MYPATH/further/down/path/
```

In all shells started as a child of the shell where you defined the variable. If you want to make it persistent you would put it in profile or bashrc scripts, so it is set on each login.

NB: if you want to concatenate letters after the variable you would have to use this:

```
cd ${MYPATH}2/other
```

and finally, if it contains blanks it does not hurt to quote the variable (but dont use `'singlequotes'` for this):

```
cd "${MYPATH}/test"
```

Comment: Thank you! export, never used that one before! This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: `export` is only needed to set the value of a variable that will be used by a *child* process, not just the current shell.

Comment: @chepner yes, I included it by default since it is not uncommon to have child shells

Answer (score 1):

`CDPATH` contains a list of directories that should be used as starting points when trying to resolve relative directories used as the argument to `cd`. For example,

```
CDPATH=/a/b/c/d/e:/a/b/c/f/g

cd bin
```

If `bin` is not a directory in the current working directory, `bash` will attempt to change first to `/a/b/c/d/e/bin`, then `/a/b/c/f/g/bin`.